# CONSTRAINT_ERROR on reading a file containing "["

Tags: ada, gnat

I am reading a simple text file. Everything works as it should, except when an open bracket ("[") character is encountered. Then I get a CONSTRAINT_ERROR.

My function is:

```
----------------------------------------------
-- GET_FILE_CONTENTS
function Get_File_Contents (File_Name : in String)
    return String_Array is
    -- Loads the entire file into a dynamically sized
    -- array of Unbounded_Wide_String.

    -- The line count is used to dynamically size the array.
    Line_Count : Natural
               := 0;

    File : Ada.Wide_Text_IO.File_Type;
begin
    -- Get the line count before opening the file.
    Line_Count := Get_File_Line_Count (File_Name);

    Ada.Wide_Text_IO.Open (File,
                           In_File,
                           File_Name);
    declare
        Lines : String_Array (1 .. Line_Count);
    begin

        -- Step through the file and save each line.
        for Current_Line in reverse 1 .. Line_Count loop
            Lines(Current_Line) := To_Unbounded_Wide_String (Ada.Wide_Text_IO.Get_Line (File));
        end loop;

    -- Remember to close the file.
    Ada.Wide_Text_IO.Close (File);
    return Lines;

end;
end Get_File_Contents;
```

The CONSTRAINT_ERROR is raised in "s-wchcnv.adb:207". The relevant part of the file is this

```
when WCEM_Brackets =>
    if C /= '[' then
       return Character'Pos (C);
    end if;

    if In_Char /= '"' then
       raise Constraint_Error; <======= CONSTRAINT_ERROR
    end if;
```

This is the info I found:

```
--  Note on the use of brackets encoding (WCEM_Brackets). The brackets
--  encoding method is ambiguous in the context of this function, since
--  there is no way to tell if ["1234"] is eight unencoded characters or
--  one encoded character. In the context of Ada sources, any sequence
--  starting [" must be the start of an encoding (since that sequence is
--  not valid in Ada source otherwise). The routines in this package use
--  the same approach. If the input string contains the sequence [" then
--  this is assumed to be the start of a brackets encoding sequence, and
--  if it does not match the syntax, an error is raised.
```

---

How do I turn this off, so that "[" aren't being interpreted as WCEM?

## Edit:

Compiler version is GNAT GPL 2014 (20140331)
Operating system is Windows 7 x64

Small program that reproduces the CONSTRAINT_ERROR:

```
with Ada.Wide_Text_IO; use Ada.Wide_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    File : File_Type;
    File_Name : String := "Data.txt";
begin
    Open (File,
          In_File,
          File_Name);

    while not End_Of_File (File) loop
    declare
        Line : Wide_String := Get_Line (File);
    begin
        Put_Line (Line);
    end;
    end loop;

    Close (File);
end Main;
```

A "Data.txt" file needs to be near the executable.

If "Data.txt" contains text as below, no problem.

```
Hello
abc
```

Add "[" and a CONSTRAINT_ERROR is raised:

```
Hello[
abc
```

Comment: Given the nature of this question I'll suggest adding the OS and Gnat compiler versions to the question. If you can work up the code into a complete compilable version (a minimal main prog, and a one-liner text file that fails), that could be useful too.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but since you're reading unbounded strings from a file: Ada has packages to support that directly, so your code won't need all the conversions to and from unbounded strings. Take a look at  `Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO` [RM A.10.12(3/2)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-12.html#I6491), `Ada.Wide_Text_IO.Unbounded_IO` and `Ada.Wide_Wide_Text_IO.Unbounded_IO` [RM  A.11(5/3)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-11.html#I6508)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I've taken your advice and included the requested info.

Comment: @egilhh Thanks a lot, I had no idea. :)

Comment: Apparently `["1234"]` is an encoding for a single wide character. I haven't found a reference to this in the RM, but the comment implies that it's something that can occur in Ada source code. It seems completely bizarre that `Wide_Text_IO` would handle its input in a way that assumes it's Ada source code. A quick experiment shows that `["1234"]` is read as `Wide_Character'Val(16#1234#)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson That was my conclusion as well, but why would it do that? It is a simple *.txt file and I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Gnat-4.9.1 (FSF) in Debian Jessie raises at the same place, so it's not limited to a single compiler version.

Comment: GNAT's `Wide_Text_IO` apparently permits any of several encodings for wide characters, [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Wide_005fText_005fIO.html). There's an open bug that looks relevant: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4304

Comment: @KeithThompson You have accidentally cut-off the last number from your link, which links to a different bug. The one you posted previously was https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43041

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks a lot for finding it, by the way.. I don't really know what I'm supposed to do now, though. Do I just avoid open brackets.. ?

Comment: Thanks to Keith's clue, add an argument `Form="WCEM=8"` to your Open call... works here. So specifying the encoding method works now. I don't know the best WCEM= option for your purpose, try others on the list (not WCEM=b !) if 8 gives trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "Form" parameter to the Open call to specify the character encoding as something other than "WCEM=b" for bracket.

```
with Ada.Wide_Text_IO; use Ada.Wide_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    File : File_Type;
    File_Name : String := "Data.txt";
begin
    Open (File,
          In_File,
          File_Name, 
          Form => "WCEM=8");

    while not End_Of_File (File) loop
    declare
        Line : Wide_String := Get_Line (File);
    begin
        Put_Line (Line);
    end;
    end loop;

    Close (File);
end Main;
```

For the relevant documentation, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Wide_005fText_005fIO.html)

Keith Thompson deserves the credit for finding the relevant documentation.