# Write emojis in Ada

Tags: emoji, ada

Forgetting about console support (I got that sorted) I have not been able to print to screen an emoji. I know utf encoding can be forced with `pragma Wide_Character_Encoding(UTF8);` but even with that emojis (and other utf-8 characters) show like gibberish. This is my code:

```
WITH Ada.Wide_Wide_Text_IO;
pragma Wide_Character_Encoding (UTF8);

procedure something IS
  Party: Wide_Wide_Character := '';
begin
  Ada.Wide_Wide_Text_IO.Put(party);
end something;
```

The result is `≡ƒÄë` which does really not look like an emoji to me. How can you display emojis (an other non-ASCII characters) in Ada?

Comment: Possibly related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486505/constraint-error-on-reading-a-file-containing/28487600#28487600 In short, there is an optional  "Form" parameter to input and output files (and Standard_Output is treated as a file) describing how to interpret character sets. Documentation link in that answer. I don't offhand know how you change the Form parameter on Standard_Output or if there is something you have to tell the console before running the executable instead.

Comment: Works fine in Terminal on a Mac! (not so great in Emacs)

Comment: Ditto, works fine in Debian 10, Gnome Terminal (whose Character Encoding is currently set to Unicode-UTF8). Please add OS/version/terminal to question if you need further help.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Using the new Windows Terminal (1.3.2651.0) in Windows 10 which technically supports emojis. Seeing your responses I used WSL to test it (in the same Terminal) on Ubuntu and I saw that the emojis (and others characters like Á) display correctly there, seems that it is more a problem with Windows rather than with Ada, Terminal or GNAT. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Works fine in GNOME Terminal on a Linux!